# using computer name with Remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, dns, home-networking

Hey there, I'm trying to remote control a computer in my home network (workgroup).

I don't have an internal DNS server.

I want to use the computer name instead of having to type the IP of the computer in every time I want to control it.

Is this possible without a DNS?

Comment: Is the computer's IP static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either edit your `hosts` file under `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc` if the IP of the computer is static:

```
169.123.123.1 MyOtherComputer
```

and you can access the computer via `//MyOtherComputer` then. You also might want to look into [NetBIOS over TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP) which gives you the ability to have speaking names on a network without a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your hosts file in %windir%\system32\drivers\etc - enter a line in the host file like this:

192.168.1.42    targetpcname

where 192.168.1.42 is the IP of the remote computer you're trying to control and targetpcname is the name of that computer.